# FirebaseMLVision doesn't recognize face from CameraImage

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-mlkit

I am using `firebase_ml_vision` to detect faces in the stream of camera images. For this, I am using

```
controller.startImageStream((CameraImage image) => detectFace(image)))

void detectFace(CameraImage image) {
   final firebaseImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBytes(
    _concatenatePlanes(cameraImage.planes), // Convert from YUV_420_888 to NV21
    _buildMetaData(cameraImage, rotation),
  );
}
```

`_concatenatePlanes, _buildMetaData, _rotation` are taken from Flutter Plugin example ([link](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_ml_vision/example/lib/scanner_utils.dart)).

But unfortunately, it is not detecting any face like this. But if I will capture same image using the camera option and then detect face on it, it works properly. My guess is there is some issue in the conversion of format.

What could be possibly wrong here and how can I fix it?

Edit - I have already tried using different values for rotation and using one more device (tried on both android platform only).

--
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some issue with the camera plugin's latest version. When I switched it to `0.5.8+1` it worked smoothly with both my application and the example too.

I have filed an issue on the owners to identify the cause and fix it forward - https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/4549#issuecomment-753448995

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing the same issues with my project.

In my case, I forgot to install the face model, as described in the readme of firebase_ml_vision:

iOS
If you're using one of the on-device APIs, include the corresponding ML Kit library model in your Podfile. Then run pod update in a terminal within the same directory as your Podfile.

```
pod 'Firebase/MLVisionBarcodeModel'
pod 'Firebase/MLVisionFaceModel'
pod 'Firebase/MLVisionLabelModel'
pod 'Firebase/MLVisionTextModel'
```

Android
If you're using the on-device Face Contour Detection, include the latest matching ML Kit: Face Detection Model dependency in your app-level build.gradle file.

```
android {
    dependencies {
        // ...

        api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-face-model:17.0.2'
    }
}
```

I also found a plug in that has all the boilerplate already implemented, i just tried and works fine flutter_camera_ml_vision:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_camera_ml_vision

And, if you want the code in a class, I also found this project that also works perfectly fine (the project needs to be updates, but the class of FaceDetection you can copy-paste to your project, which is a very similar code that you have, this works just fine:
https://github.com/giandifra/Flutter-Smile-Face-Detection/blob/master/lib/face_detection_camera.dart